Get the groups that returned a match in Java Regex
I'm coding a simple Lexer in Java and the class looks like this:
public class Lexer {
    // This enum contains all the possible tokens accepted by the language and their respective regular expression
    private enum PossibleTokens {
        NUM("\\d+"),
        SUM("\\+"),
        SUB("-"),
        MULT("\\*"),
        DIV("/"),
        LPAREN("\\("),
        RPAREN("\\)");
        
        public Pattern pattern;
        
        private PossibleTokens (String ptrnString) {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(ptrnString);
        }
    }
    private String input;
    private Pattern tokensPattern;
    
    // Constructor for the Lexer class
    public Lexer(String input) {
        this.input = input;
        this.tokensPattern = createTokensPattern();
    }

    private Pattern createTokensPattern() {
        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
    
        // Creating tokens pattern using the token's name for a named-capturing group
        for (PossibleTokens token : PossibleTokens.values()) {
            pattern.append(String.format("|(?<%s>%s)", token.name(), token.pattern));
        }
    
        return Pattern.compile(pattern.substring(1));
    }

    // This is the main method of the class
    public LinkedList<Token> tokenize() {
        // Create a matcher for the input string
        Matcher matcher = tokensPattern.matcher(input);

        // Create an empty list for the result
        LinkedList<Token> tokensList = new LinkedList<>();

        // While matches are found, keep looping        
        while (matcher.find()) {
            // Get match
            String matchStr = matcher.group();
            
            // Check witch token matched to create the apropriate Token object
            for(PossibleTokens t : PossibleTokens.values()) {
                if (matcher.group(t.name()) != null)
                    tokensList.add(new Token(t.name(), matchStr));
            }
        }
        
        // Return list of Tokens
        return tokensList;
    }
}

The code works as expected, but something I don't really like in the tokenize() method is that to verify which group have matched I need to loop through all of them and verify which one is not null.
Is there a better method to get the matched group without having to loop through all of the groups?
This would be very useful because I plan to expand the tokens that this Lexer accepts in the future. Therefore, check each group every time would be very inefficient.

You can create a static map of name -> token and iterate over the groups instead. But it probably won't make a huge difference, unless you have a lot of tokens and not many capturing groups.

But you'd have to declare the group names separately, because it's not exposed by the Java API.

Hello @shmosel! I posted the entire code for the class in my question. Now it's more clear how the Lexer works. The idea of creating a map will not be very useful unfortunately, as it would be necessary to check each group too.

I see. Maybe regex isn't the best tool for this.

It won't be much of a difference but as your regex groups are distinct then you should be able to break the values() loop after tokensList.add. Note also that if you want to re-use a Lexer for multiple inputs then you should have tokenize(String input) and re-use the Matcher (reset).
